# Mogodb aggregation create output as {"key": "value"} from 2 arrays

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql-aggregation

I have a question about how to create output from 2 arrays one array with translation key and another with translation i would output as

```
"translation_key":"value"
```

Current output:
     {

```
        "_id" : ObjectId("5bfc0b2b30c4683f585078fb"),
        "translation" : [ 
            "hour", 
            "day"

        ],
        "translation_key" : [ 
            "HOUR_TEXT", 
            "DAY_TEXT"  


        ],
        "locale_id" : "EN_en"
   }
```

OUTPUT should be :

```
{
    "EN_en" :{
        "HOUR_TEXT" :"hour",
        "DAY_TEXT" :"day",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            array: [
                {
                    k: "$locale_id",
                    v: {
                        $arrayToObject: {
                            $map: {
                                input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$translation" }] },
                                as: "index",
                                in: {
                                    k: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$translation", "$$index" ] },
                                    v: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$translation_key", "$$index" ] }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: { $arrayToObject: "$array" }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically you need to use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) operator to manipulate your key names and in your case it should be used twice. This operator expects an array of objects with two properties `k` and `v` and therefore you should use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to generate that values based on `translation`, [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) is used to generate indexes to traverse `translation` and `translation_key` arrays. Then you can use [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to promote dynamically generated key into root level of your document.

Output:

```
{ "EN_en" : { "hour" : "HOUR_TEXT", "day" : "DAY_TEXT" } }
```

Comment: and how could i do this ...  from ...
{
    "EN_en" : {
        "hour" : "HOUR_TEXT",
        "day" : "DAY_TEXT"
    }
}


{
    "ES_en" : {
        "hour" : "HOUR_TEXT",
        "day" : "DAY_TEXT"
    }
} to ... {"EN_en" : { "key":value}},"ES_es":{"key":value"}} }

Comment: You need to push multiple documents into `array`

Comment: {
    "0" : {
        "test12" : {
            "in about a year" : ""
        }
    },
    "1" : {
        "q23221312" : {
            "in about a year" : ""
        }
    },
    "2" : {
        "ES_es" : {
            "in about a year" : ""
        }
    },
    "3" : {
        "EN_en" : {
            "in about a year" : "in about a year"
        }
    }
} how to do that ? what i wrote 1 comment  before ? :o

Comment: @Maco please open a separate question just to avoid confusion and let this question be simple and clear for future users, I will try to take a look at this new question

Answer (score 3):

You can use below aggregation

You can use [**`$range`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) to get index from both the arrays and can create key `(k)` and value `(v)` pair for the resultant array and then finally [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) to convert resultant array into single document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {
      "$arrayToObject": [[
        {
          "k": "$locale_id",
          "v": {
            "$arrayToObject": {
              "$map": {
                "input": { "$range": [0, { "$size": "$translation_key" }] },
                "in": {
                  "k": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$translation_key", "$$this"] },
                  "v": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$translation", "$$this"] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]]
    }
  }}
])
```

Which returns

```
[
  {
    "EN_en": {
      "DAY_TEXT": "day",
      "HOUR_TEXT": "hour"
    }
  }
]
```